# Efficient way to match two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary-search

I have 2 arrays , one is inputs `pins names`, the other is their `actual numbers`.

```
const char *pins[]={"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","o1","o2","o3","o4"};
const int pinsNumbers[9]={1,2,19,4,14,6,12,15,17};
```

When I get as an input **"d3"** , I would like to find the corresponding - **19** .

1. Is there more efficient way to save these "matches" ?
2. How would one loop over the pins array with an input and find its match- as efficiently as possible ?

Comment: A more efficient way than what ? You haven't implemented anything.

Comment: efficient way to save it . I would also like to know how to implement it in a good way.

Comment: Use a map instead of 2 arrays.

Comment: And now you loop over the `pins` and strcmp and use `pinsNumbers[i]` when the cmp matches.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you show example? I guess this is the kind of things I am looking for. Oh, if its not C so its not good.

Comment: @GillBates I know. He can use a library that offers that data structure.

Comment: There is no "efficient solution" without actual restrictions. How long is the `pins` array? How often will you query for a pin number?

Comment: As @m0skit0 wrote, you need a map from string to int. It is commonly done using a hash table (`O(1)` on average), or a binary search (`O(logN)` on average). But if it's a rather short array, you can simply iterate through the `pins` array and find the index.

Comment: I would recommend using an existing library like [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), where you already have many data structures implemented.

Answer (score 4):

If the array pins is ordered (otherwise you can sort it using for example `qsort`) then you can use the following approach as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const char *lhs = *( const char ** )a;
    const char *rhs = *( const char ** )b;

    return strcmp( lhs, rhs );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *pins[]      = { "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "o1", "o2", "o3", "o4" };
    const int pinsNumbers[] = { 1, 2, 19, 4, 14, 6, 12, 15, 17 };

    const char *key = "d3";

    const char **p = bsearch( &key, pins, sizeof( pins ) / sizeof( *pins ), sizeof( const char * ), cmp );

    if ( p ) printf( "%d\n", pinsNumbers[p - pins] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
19
```

Answer (score 3):

You can structure your data like this to emulate a C++ map:

```
struct My_pair {
    const char* pin;
    int number;
};

const My_pair pairs[] = {
    {"d1", 1},
    {"d2", 2},
    ...
};
```

Comment: This is still `O(N)`.

Comment: @GillBates but at least the data structure is less error prone than the OP's.

Comment: @GillBates Feel free to improve :)

Comment: So is this different from just looping over the 2 arrays and get the index from one to use in the other ?

Comment: @Curnelious Performance wise? No. Use a hashmap for that. It does bring safety.

Comment: @Curnelious it's not more efficient, but using 2 arrays as in your question is error prone. Imageine you add another pin "d6", then you must add the pin number in the `pinsNumbers` array at the correct position, otherways everything will get mixed up. With the `struct` solution you would just add another entry such as `{"d6", 18}` into the initializer list of the `pairs` array.

Answer (score 2):

As easy and fast as it is possible. And if you will use two consecutive symbols (for example `'a'` and  `'b'`) - you can calculate and check it just as offset inside groups in code bellow. [Ideone online executable code.](http://ideone.com/DcPhwm)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define D1_VAL  1
#define D2_VAL  2
#define D3_VAL  19
#define D4_VAL  4
#define D5_VAL  14

#define D_CNT   5
#define D_OFS   0

#define O1_VAL  6
#define O2_VAL  12
#define O3_VAL  15
#define O4_VAL  17

#define O_CNT   4
#define O_OFS   D_CNT

#define PIN_NUM_CNT     (D_CNT+O_CNT)
#define PIN_GRP_CNT     2

enum decode_res_e {
    DECODE_OK = 0,
    DECODE_ERR = !DECODE_OK
};

int const pin_num_tab[PIN_NUM_CNT] = {
    D1_VAL, D2_VAL, D3_VAL, D4_VAL, D5_VAL,
    O1_VAL, O2_VAL, O3_VAL, O4_VAL,
};

typedef struct { unsigned char chr, ofs, cnt; } pin_grp_t;

pin_grp_t const pin_grp_tab[2] = {
    { .chr = 'd', .ofs = D_OFS, .cnt = D_CNT },
    { .chr = 'o', .ofs = O_OFS, .cnt = O_CNT },
};

int pin_to_num(int * num, unsigned char * pin)
{
    unsigned char i = 0, tmp = pin[1] - 0x31;
    while (i < PIN_GRP_CNT) {
        if (pin_grp_tab[i].chr == pin[0]) {
            if (tmp >= pin_grp_tab[i].cnt) break;
            *num = pin_num_tab[pin_grp_tab[i].ofs + tmp];
            return DECODE_OK;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return DECODE_ERR;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int num;
    unsigned char const inp[] = "d3";
    printf("\f%s is ",inp);
    if (pin_to_num(&num,inp) == DECODE_OK) {
        printf("%d\r\n",num);
    } else {
        printf("err\r\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)...as long as the array above is sorted.

Comment: They're obviously not sorted in the example.

Comment: @m0skit0: OP probably doesn't care about the index of the actual element, just the mapping.

Comment: @m0skit0 they _are_ sorted in the OP's question and even if they weren't, the OP could sort them.

Comment: That's rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: thanks but I can't comment in the first place since I haven't 50 reputations  :(